# Pycharm valid escape sequence messes with path strings

Tags: python, escaping, pycharm, sequence

I would like to set a path as a string to some random variable. When i do that, Pycharm thinks the path has valid escape sequences.
Instead of taking the path as is, it changes parts of it to different patterns:
\f changes to \x0c and \a to \x07 and so on.
How do I prevent it to do so?
Sorry for not linking the code, I am not allowed.

Comment: could you provide  a code example?, also is your problem solved if you use \\ to escape \

Answer (score 2):

Did not work with \ but with / instead.
Thanks

Comment: This may be an OS issue also. \ works in windows, but / works in all OS. Consider accepting your answer as valid.